# Is SQL Server able to use internal parallelism for an update statement?

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, internals, dml

I am struggling to find the best way to migrate some `varchar` columns to `nvarchar`. One of the options I am using is to add new `nvarchar` column, then update the values from the original column, drop the original column and rename the new one to the old name.

I know it will generate a lot of UNDO and REDO data. Still, I have other limitations (mostly by SQL Server not supporting parallel DDLs and multi-column `ALTER TABLE` operations), so let's focus on how to run the update statement faster.

My Oracle experience is telling me to use internal parallelism, but is it available in SQL Server?

I am not able to run this statement in parallel, although I especially created the table to be a heap table (no clustered index).

```
update t 
set new_col_1 = col_1,   
    new_col_2 = col_2, 
    ..., 
    new_col_N = col_N ;
```

Thanks in advance!!

I read the documentation but have not find an exact proof that parallel update plans are possible.

Comment: 1. Did you check the configuration setting for Maximum Degree of Parallelism. 2. Personally I'm not sure if it's possible to effiently control the number of threads that SQL uses for UPDATE. 3. Have you creating a unique index, and few jobs that each job will do the update to to different chunks of the table?

Comment: 1. The max degree is set to 0, which will allow the runtime to decide on the number of paralell threads.        2. It is not about control over number of threads, it is about not using a parallel plan at all              3. I am using a heap table as a target on purpose. Otherwise pa

Comment: Not sure on updates tbh but definitely with a heap and inserts, specifying a *tablock* hint allows for a parallel plan.

Comment: Well, i did my homework.. the only parallel operations i am able to use are: select into (since 2014), insert select ( since 2016), create index...all the rest is just in the mist. But lets focus on update. Any clue how to get it? Test case will be great